# Delete duplicate user mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

A duplicate user was created by mistake using the "grant" command.
how can i delete the duplicate user, leaving the "active" user intact?

```
 host.ras.com | usercpm | 08fbc0566c63e668 | N           | N           
| host.ras.com | usercpm | 08fbc0566c63e668 | N           | N
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select the top row of that user and delete it with this command,

```
DELETE TOP(1)
FROM 'TableName'
WHERE UserName='host.ras.com'
```

Comment: Its hard to tell you what you want without knowing how the table is laid out.